# PHP Filter a specific word

Tags: php, web, filter

My output from the mysql database looks like this:
***icon-search icon-white*** (from bootstrap framework)

And now I want, that it only displays ***icon-search*** without the ***icon-white*** string.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If `$var` contains **icon-search icon white**, try it this way:

```
$var = str_replace(' icon-white', '', $var);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo str_replace("icon-white", "", $your_output);
```

Or for the sake of being a little more pedantic on what icon-white strings to remove something like this would work too

```
echo preg_replace("/(class=[\'\"].*?)(\s*icon\-white\s*)(.*?[\'\"])/i", "\\1\\3", $your_output);
```

Comment: Added a regex which would work too so it only removes the class and not generic strings

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer need the text icon-white, just update the values in database:

```
UPDATE you_table SET you_column = REPLACE(you_column, ' icon-white', '') WHERE you_conditional;
```

This will increase the performance of your application, but if you still need the text, then use the solution of Edd.